# Sequilize bind parameter not returning multiple dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am working with sequelize and met with a condition where I am not using models, I am using raw SQL query.

My query is `select emp, salary from table_a where col1 = 'name' and col2 = 'user'`
Now I want to bind my parameter with the query.
As mentioned in the doc i write the query as `await sequelize.query('select emp, salary from table_a where col1 = $name and col2 = $user', {bind: {name: 'abc', user: 'xyz'}, type: QueryTypes.SELECT})`.
It is returning only a single record but when I am running the same in SQL it's returning multiple records.

Comment: Can you try replacements instead of bind to see if it still return you 1 result?
await sequelize.query('select emp, salary from table_a where col1 = :name and col2 = :user', {replacements: {name: 'abc', user: 'xyz'}, type: QueryTypes.SELECT})

Comment: @MicFung I tried that as well but it's not returning the multiple data. As with replacement dialect in the query is : only

Comment: is the console showing the right sql? There should be a sql output in the console `Executing (default): SELECT emp, salary FROM table_a where col1 = 'abc' and col2 = 'xyz'`

Comment: It works fine now, whitespaces are the issue. Anyways thanks